# App id <TeamAppID> needs to be installed to the scope <TeamID>:<ChannelId> and be in an unblocked state to install/update a tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When I am running the below given Graph API Call,I am getting the error as above.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/< TeamId >/channels/< ChannelId >/tabs

```
{"displayName":"Transform","teamsApp@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/<TeamID>","name":"Transform","configuration":{"entityId":null,"contentUrl":"<Url>","websiteUrl":"<Url>","removeUrl":null}}
```

If I add this personal app in that channel manually, and then run this API , it will work.
My requirement is to do that automatically.

Comment: It sounds like the app might possibly be blocked at a tenant level - could that be the case? Check policies in Teams Tenant admin

Comment: I am not sure what has worked, but I am able to get that working, If I wait for around 3-4 mins before hitting the above API for the newly created team channel it is working. So I guess it is taking some time to reflect the new channel details for the API to work